# "'module' object is not callable" error when creating a class in python

Tags: python, class

I main java and just started on python, and I ran into this error when I was trying to create a class. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
import rectangle

a = rectangle(4, 5)

print(a.getArea())
```

this is what is in the rectangle class:

```
class rectangle:
    l = 0
    w = 0

    def __init__(self, l, w):
        self.l = l
        self.w = w

    def getArea(self):
        return self.l * self.w

    def getLength(self):
        return self.l

    def getWidth(self):
        return self.w

    def __str__(self):
        return "this is a", self.l, "by", self.w, "rectangle with an area of", self.getArea()
```

Comment: Please, don't post images of code, error, etc. Copy/paste as properly formatted text block here.

Comment: how do u insert a code block?

Comment: @ir6 See: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: your calling rectangle as a class when it's a module, if you do have the rectangle class inside of the rectangle object, you would need to do `rectangle.rectangle(4,5) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you have implemented in the rectangle module but I suspect that what you're actually looking for is this:

```
from rectangle import rectangle
a = rectangle(4, 5)
print(a.getArea())
```

If not, give us an indication of what's in rectangle.py

Comment: nice it work! ty!

Comment: Thought so :) Just so you know, when you do `import recrangle`, you add the rectangle MODULE (file) to the namespace. If you want to call the class using that, you would have had to do `a = rectangle.rectangle(4, 5)`. In that case, the first rectangle is the name of the module, while the second rectangle is the name of the class. On the other hand, `from rectangle import rectangle` tells the interpreter that from the module rectangle import class rectangle and add that to the namespace. Hope that helps you understand this better :) Don't forget to thumbs up and accept the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Also, piece of advice in the future, it's usually a good practice to name the modules with lower case and the classes with upper case. Meaning you would have `class Rectangle:` and you'd import it as `from rectangle import Rectangle`. This helps distinguish if rectangle that you import into the namespace is a class (uppercase) or a function (lowercase). Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

your gonna need to specify what module the function is from
so either import all the functions
so change `import rectangle`  to `from rectangle import *`

or switch the `rectangle(4,5)` to `rectangle.rectangle(4,5)`

Comment: star import is considered bad style